# Show that $\|T\|\le\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\|T_n\|$ under both the weak and strong operator topologies on $B(X,Y)$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I have shown that whenever $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ in $X$, then $\|x\|\le\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|$ and have also managed to demonstrate the analogous result for when $f_n\overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}f$ in $X^*$. In the proof of the former we make recourse to the Hahn Banach theorem, whereas in the latter there is no such need.

**I'm interested in showing the corresponding result as well for a sequence of bounded linear operators under the strong and weak operator topologies**.

To clarify, $T_n\overset{SOT}\to T\in B(X,Y)$ means that $\forall x\in X$, $\|T_nx-Tx\|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, and, $T_n\overset{WOT}\to T\in B(X,Y)$ means that $\forall x\in X$, and $f\in Y^*,$ $|f(T_nx)-f(Tx)|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Here are my attempts so far. We start with the strong operator topology case, and then will do the weak operator topology case.

---

**1.**$\,$Suppose that $T_n\overset{SOT}\to T\in B(X,Y)$. Then $\forall x\in X$, $\|T_nx-Tx\|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Choose $x\in X:\|x\|=1$, and let $\epsilon\gt0$.

Now, $\|Tx\|\le\|T\|\implies\|Tx\|\gt\|T\|-\epsilon$.

But $\|T_nx\|\to\|Tx\|$ by strong operator convergence. So that, for large enough $n\in\mathbb N$, $\|T_nx\|\gt\|T\|-\epsilon.$ But, $\|T_nx\|\le\|T_n\|$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, so that furthermore, $\|T_n\|\ge\|T\|-\epsilon.$

But then, this impliex that $\|T\|-\epsilon\le\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\|T_n\|$, on taking lim infs of both sides. Which further implies that $\|T\|\le\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\|T_n\|$, since $\epsilon\gt0$ was arbitrary. Thus showing the result we required.

---

**2.**$\,$Suppose that $T_n\overset{WOT}\to T\in B(X,Y)$. Then $\forall x\in X$, and $f\in Y^*,$ $|f(T_nx)-f(Tx)|\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. Now the Hahn Banach theorem tells us that $\exists f\in X^*:\|f\|=1$ and that $f(x)=\|x\|$.

With this in mind, consider that $|f(T_nx)|\le\|T_n\|$, using the boundedness of $f$, $T_n,\,\forall n\in \mathbb N$ and the above observations from Hahn Banach.

But $|f(T_nx)|\to|f(Tx)|\le\|T\|$, by the weak operator convergence and then the boundedness and Hahn Banach deductions.

On putting both of these observations together, we see that $\|T\|\le\|T_n\|$, and so on taking lim infs, we get that $\|T\|\le\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\|T_n\|$, as required.

---

Are both of these attempts correct? Or are there any ways in which I could improve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the SOT attempt, you are first choosing $x$. But then you cannot guarantee that $\|Tx\|\geq\|T\|-\epsilon$. What you need to do is to choose $x$ so that $\|x\|=1$ and $\|Tx\|\geq\|T\|-\varepsilon$. Then, by the convergence, you find that for $ n$ big enough , $\|T_nx\|\geq\|Tx\|-\epsilon$. Thus, for $n$ big enough, 
$$
\|T_n\|\geq\|T_nx\|\geq\|Tx\|-\epsilon\geq\|T\|-2\epsilon. 
$$
Now you conclude that $\liminf_n\|T_n\|\geq\|T\|-2\epsilon$.

In the WOT attempt, you are glossing so much that it is hard to see what you are doing. There is no inequality whatsoever with $\|T\|$ on the low side, so it is hard to see how you conclude; you don't say how you choose $x$. The way I would do it to first notice that, by Hahn-Banach, 
$$
\|Tx\|=\sup\{|f(Tx)|:\ f\in Y^*,\ \|f\|=1\}.
$$
So, fix $x$. Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $f\in Y^*$ with $\|f\|=1$ and 
$$
\|Tx\|\leq|f(Tx)|+\varepsilon=\lim_n|f(T_nx)|+\varepsilon. 
$$
As $|f(T_nx)|\leq\|T_n\|$, we get $\lim_n|f(T_nx)|\leq\liminf_n\|T_n\|$. Thus
$$
\|Tx\|\leq\liminf_n\|T_n\|+\varepsilon.
$$
As this works with any $x$ with $\|x\|=1$, taking supremum we get 
$$
\|T\|\leq\liminf_n\|T_n\|+\varepsilon, 
$$
and we finally can remove the $\varepsilon$ since its aritrarily small.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll have another go at it and try be clearer in the areas you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $T_n \xrightarrow{SOT} T$. For every $x \in X$ we have

$$\|Tx\| = \lim_{n\to\infty} \|T_nx\| \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \|T_n\|\|x\| = \left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} \|T_n\|\right)\|x\|$$

Therefore $\|T\| \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \|T_n\|$.

---

Assume $T_n \xrightarrow{WOT} T$ and take $x \in X$. The Hanh-Banach theorem implies that there exists $f \in Y^*$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ and $f(Tx) = \|Tx\|$. We have

$$\|Tx\| = |f(Tx)| = \lim_{n\to\infty} |f(T_n x)| \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \overbrace{\|f\|}^{=1}\|T_nx\| \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \|T_n\|\|x\| = \left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} \|T_n\|\right) \|x\|$$

Therefore $\|T\| \le \liminf_{n\to\infty} \|T_n\|$.